# sharing a common state among duplicate react component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have one doubt regarding state of component. I have one tile component. On click of tile component I am toggling the details of tile component.

```
/* ---- Tile component ---- */

                import React, { Component } from 'react';
                import TileDetail from './TileDetail';

                class Tile extends Component {
                   constructor(props) {
                        super(props);

                        this.state = {
                            isTileDetailOpened:false
                        };
                        this.showTileDetails=this.showTileDetails.bind(this);
                    }

                    showTileDetails(networkName){
                     this.setState({isTileDetailOpened:!this.state.isTileDetailOpened});
                     alert(networkName);
                    }

                    render() {
                        const isTileDetailOpened = this.state.isTileDetailOpened;
                    return (
                    <li  className={ !this.state.isTileDetailOpened ? "tile-item" : "tile-item-with-detail" }> 
                       <div onClick={(e) => this.showTileDetails(this.props.objTile.network_name)}>
                        {this.props.objTile.network_name}
                       </div>
                          {this.state.isTileDetailOpened ? <TileDetail /> : <div/>}
                    </li>
                    );
                  }
                }

                export default Tile;

        /* ---- Tile Detail component ---- */
            import React, { Component } from 'react';


            class TileDetail extends Component {
              render() {
                return (
                 <div className="tile-detail">
                    <p>TileDetails</p>
                 </div>
                );
              }
            }
export default TileDetail;
```

As you can see, I am toggling the tile detail on click of tile click and its working fine.
 I am rendering collecting of tiles on my page. And it works fine if I click on individual tile. But What I want if I am seeing the detail of one tile other tile details should be always hidden.
Could you please guide me on this. Completely new on React JS

Comment: You need to store your `isTileDetailOpened` inside `TileDetail` component. Try doing that. It will work. If you are unable to figure out how, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make use of the parent component of the `Tile` to achieve this. In the parent component have a state like `currentlyTileDetailOpened`. In `showTileDetails` call a method via props to set the value of this state(currentlyTileDetailOpened) to the `id` of the current `Tile`. Pass this state to the `Tile` component as a prop. In `render` method of `Tile`, check the prop instead of state and render it like

```
{this.props.currentlyOpenedTile === tile.id ? <TileDetail /> : null}
```

Comment: thanks buddy!  works like charm. just wanted to know whether its a good way of doing that. ?? Redux is something we can use here?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with a pagination control unit I made by storing the page info in Redux, and then making a special option in the second paginator so that it just used the `Redux data` instead of "double performing" the same work (and thus also not going out of sync with the first paginator).

It's like this (you could do the same with setting the parent's state (ie: first common ancestor):

```
    <Pagination
      pageSize={25}
      items={(!this.state.fuzzyMatches.length)
        ? this.props.businesses
        : this.state.fuzzyMatches}
      onChangePage={(pagerState) => this.handlePageChange(pagerState)}
      activePage={this.props.activePage}
      isEmpty={((this.state.search.length > 0) &&
        (this.state.fuzzyMatches.length === 0))}
      bottom                                           // bottom = true
      bottomData={this.props.pagination}               // get data from here
    />
```

Now, inside the paginator, instead of the normal logic, it does this:

```
render() {
  const pager = (this.props.bottom)
    ? this.props.bottomData
    : this.state.pager
```

The `bottom = true` prop is actually just to handle a slight CSS difference, but you can see, the first paginator creates the details, and the second one simply uses those instead of duplicating. I have told the second component to skip all its internal work and just use the data that is passed in.